# How do you set the data values in a component with Vue-Test-Utils before mounted is called?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I am using Jest with Vue-Test-Utils. The code I have been using looks like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallow(GridContainer, {
    data: {
      pageSize: count
    },
    propsData: {
      userId,
      managerId
    }
  })
})
```

In this example, I want to set the pageSize value before the life cycle mounted is called. The problem with the above code is that I have started getting the following warning when the tests run:

```
[Vue warn]: Do not use built-in or reserved HTML elements as component id: data
```

When I delete the data property above, the warning goes away.

Am I setting the data correctly? If so, what should I do about the warning?

Should I set the data another way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please try like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallow(GridContainer, {
    propsData: {
     userId,
     managerId
    }
  })
 wrapper.setData({pageSize: count})
})
```

reference: setData
https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/api/wrapper/setData.html

Comment: If you do this make sure to await, because this is an async action.

Answer (score 17):

The solution for me was to define the data as a function within the initialisation:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallow(GridContainer, {
    propsData: {
      userId,
      managerId
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        pageSize: count
      }
    }
  })
})
```

In my case, the solution provided by yukihirop using `setData()` did not work.

My component was accessing data from the window object which was undefined within my test environment. This data was being output within the template. This caused an exception to be thrown immediately after mounting - before I had a chance to call `setData()`.

Comment: Can confirm doing it your way means the component is only rendered once

Answer (score 1):

The solution of [Nicolas Betsworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4572002/nicholas-betsworth) is correct, however, it is also possible to use setData with Vue.nextTick(). Vue.nextTick() will rerender the component.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallow(GridContainer, {
    propsData: {
     userId,
     managerId
    }
  })
 wrapper.setData({pageSize: count})
 Vue.nextTick()
})
```

[Vue.nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?#Vue-nextTick)

Comment: If you are using async, you can await the `wrapper.setData`, and then you don't need the `nextTick()`.